# Can't reduce the height of the textbox

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Can't override and reduce the height of a bootstrap textbox.

```
     <div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-xl-3">Posted Speed Limit (mph)</label><input type="text" class="col-xl-1 ps" autocomplete="off" id="sl" onkeydown="return keyval(event)" onkeyup="return valkey(event)" name="num3" required="required"><span id="rspan" class="rspan"><span>&#9888;</span>Enter a numeric value > 0 and ≤ 90</span></input>
</div>
```

The above is my input tag and below is the css for class = "ps"

```
    .ps{
  min-height: 2%;
}
```

I can't increase or reduce the height. when it comes to the width, I can increase it but can't reduce it.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Instead of percentage(%), increase it with pixel(px). Width works as expected

Comment: Thank you, but I can't reduce it and what about the height?

Comment: Example jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/9j71u6gv/3/

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I am building a responsive webpage and I was told to not use px. Any alternate ways to reduce weight and height?

Comment: what wrong with using px? since it's a standard css unit. You can use other like em [css units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code. In my opinion, you should try with id.  It may happen that the CSS of the col-xl-1 class is overwritten on your CSS. Or else what you can try is **!important** to emphasize your CSS code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #txtBox1 {
            margin: 10px;
            min-height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="col-xl-1 ps" id="txtBox1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you bro. I tried !important earlier and it didn't seem to work. I'll adjust with px for now.

Comment: I have edited it with a code. Kindly refer to this code.